# Is there a way to convert a JSON to C# class who have a List<Object> as a parameter?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Is there a way in Unity to parse JSON string to a C# class that have a list of -  lets suppose - string?

I have an application that get a lot of data from a server. That data comes in a JSON and it have a lot of fields. Some fields have another array in it (I know the ones who have an array inside and the ones who don't).

Knowing this I want to make it into a class so I can access it's parameters, [I can't create an array and try to access - for example - arr[0], because arr[0] may not be the field that I want - given that the array positions can change, but the field-key (or field-field-key if the array have an array inside) value will not]

```
{
  "success": "1",
  "menus": [
    {
      "id_menu": "506",
      "nome": "Blog",
      "tipo": "blog"
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "510",
      "nome": "Sobre",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "2407",
      "nome": "(Projeto Quatro Artes)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "2603",
      "nome": "(Loja)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "2687",
      "nome": "(Material NA)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "2818",
      "nome": "(Forms)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "2826",
      "nome": "(PHP+PIZZA)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "7728",
      "nome": "(Image)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "3239",
      "nome": "(jc)",
      "tipo": ""
    },
    {
      "id_menu": "6024",
      "nome": "(assinatura)",
      "tipo": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

The code above is one of the JSONS that I want to parse, and the code below is the class that I made to parse it. Now i just need to know how to do it.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Menu
{
    public string id_menu { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Return
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> menus { get; set; }
}
```

I know that JsonUtility.FromJson() can do the job if there isn't any lists, but with lists it just doesn't work
Also, trying to use JSONObject from Unity assets also doesn't work because I can't access return.menus.tipo (as an example) because it doesn't have an associative index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the following way:

```cs
var returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Return>(json);
```

In order for this to work, you need the following package: **Newtonsoft.Json**

The result is as follow:
[image]

I made a small console app, which shows you the way. It should be the same in Unity:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace IoException
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Menu
    {
        public string id_menu { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Return
    {
        public string success { get; set; }
        public List<Menu> menus { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonExercise
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var currentLine = Console.ReadLine();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (currentLine != "END")
            {
                sb.AppendLine(currentLine);

                currentLine = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            var json = sb.ToString().Trim();

            var returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Return>(json);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Notes about the console app, in case you want to try it:

- When you enter the JSON, enter "END" as the last line, in order for the console app to stop reading.
- For the input JSON, I used the one that you provided.

Comment: Just to make sure to other ppl.
Newtonsoft doesn't work with Unity3D, Normally. But someone forked it and made it work!
https://github.com/codecapers/Unity.Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use `Json.NET` or another deserializer that has full support for arbitrary types?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string id_menu { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public List<string> my_list {get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But unfortunately Unity3D don't let me use the Newtonsoft library. It get a lot of conflict with classes in Unity that it is not possible to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to parse the Json via Unity, you can use the JsonUtility.FromJson(jsonString), it will parse the Json to an Object, that it can handle, but I never tried using with complex JSONs.

Or you can run through the json and search for the key value that you want, but it sure does increase on memory consumption.

Comment: Yes, and for some reason it doesn't work, the values "success" and the List get nothing in it.